# ¿Al eliminar una posición de la lista se elimina la última?

Tags: html, c#, lista, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Al agregar un detalle a la tabla `html` agrega una fila con los datos registrados de manera dinámica, al lado de cada registro tiene un botón eliminar y este debe eliminar solo la fila pero al realizar el metodo **remove** elimina la última fila de la tabla.

He intentado debuggear y si obtiene la posición de la fila pero el problema es que al visualizar se elimina la última fila de la lista pero en el `controller` si se visualiza que se elimino el registro seleccionado.

Lineas abajo esta el script de como realizo la eliminacion de una fila en especifica obteniendo la posición de la fila para poder eliminar.

Script Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var model = new DataActaOUViewModel
            {
                dataBl = new DataBL(),
                lstDataBl = new List<DataBL>()
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(DataActaOUViewModel modelo, string boton = null)
        {
            if (modelo == null)
            {
                modelo = new DataActaOUViewModel();
            }

            if (boton == null)
            {
                if (CrearFactura(modelo))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Create");
                }
            }
            else if (boton == "agregar-detalle")
            {
                modelo.lstDataBl.Add(modelo.dataBl);
            }
            else if (boton.StartsWith("eliminar-detalle-"))
            {
                EliminarDetallePorIndice(modelo, boton);
            }
            return View(modelo);
        }

        private bool CrearFactura(DataActaOUViewModel modelo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (modelo.lstDataBl != null && modelo.lstDataBl.Count > 0)
                {
                    //factura.Id = facturas.Count > 0 ? facturas.Max(x => x.Id) + 1 : 1;
                    //facturas.Add(factura);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "No puede guardar actas sin detalle");
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private static void EliminarDetallePorIndice(DataActaOUViewModel model, string operacion)
        {
            string indexStr = operacion.Replace("eliminar-detalle-", "");
            int index = 0;

            if (int.TryParse(indexStr, out index) && index >= 0 && index < model.lstDataBl.Count)
            {
                var item = model.lstDataBl.ToArray()[index];
                model.lstDataBl.Remove(item);
            }
        }
```

Script Vista

```
@model MaestroDetalle.Models.DataActaOUViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<fieldset>
    <legend>Factura</legend>

    <label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Documento)</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Documento, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NombresApellidos)</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NombresApellidos, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Operador)</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Operador, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OperacionUsual)</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OperacionUsual, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Operacion)</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Operacion, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Manifiesto)</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Manifiesto, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dam)</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dam, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </label>
    <hr />
    <label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dataBl.Bl)</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dataBl.Bl, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dataBl.Contenedor)</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dataBl.Contenedor, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dataBl.Precinto)</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dataBl.Precinto, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dataBl.Bultos)</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dataBl.Bultos, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dataBl.DescripcionCarga)</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dataBl.DescripcionCarga, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </label>


    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>BL</th>
                <th>Contenedor</th>
                <th>Precinto</th>
                <th>Bultos</th>
                <th>Descripcion Carga</th>
                <th><button type="submit" name="boton" data-val="false" value="agregar-detalle" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar Detalle</button></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null && Model.lstDataBl != null && Model.lstDataBl.Count > 0)
            {
                var i = 0;

                foreach (var item in Model.lstDataBl)
                {
                    var i = Model.lstDataBl.IndexOf(item);
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.TextBox("lstDataBl[" + i + "].Bl", item.Bl.ToString())</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBox("lstDataBl[" + i + "].Contenedor", item.Contenedor)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBox("lstDataBl[" + i + "].Precinto", item.Precinto)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBox("lstDataBl[" + i + "].Bultos", Convert.ToString(item.Bultos))</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBox("lstDataBl[" + i + "].DescripcionCarga", item.DescripcionCarga)</td>
                        <td><button type="submit" name="boton" value="eliminar-detalle-@i">Eliminar</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    i++;
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Crear" />
    </p>
</fieldset>}
```

Comment: Yo tengo una duda.. te elimina la ultima fila de que tabla?? o sea, tu controlador elimina el objeto correcto, pero tu problema es la vista? o es al reves? no queda claro...

Comment: @gbianchi yo realizo el debug y elimina correctamente el registro con la posicion obtenida pero al visualizar vista elimina el ultimo registro.

Comment: Tu vista se refresca toda? yo no veo nada que elimine filas a mano... es raro.. capaz alguien se da cuenta mas queyo...